# How to encode a url in a website

Tags: urlencode

This is my code,

```
if ($r == 'donald') {
        echo '<script>window.location.href="test.php"</script>';
    }
```

How do i do it in a way that when the website display the url it would be encoded?
I know it got to do something with the urlencode function. In this case how do i use it and it would be nice if you could show it to me  :D thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming URL is stored in $url:

```
$url="http://www.google.com";
if ($r == 'donald') {
  echo "<script>window.location.href=\"".urlencode($url)."\" </script>";
}
```

Comment: erm sorry but how do you store the URL?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  By "store" I mean something like:  $url = "http://www.test.org" or whatever URL you need to use.  To get the current URL of the page you can use $url=$PHP_SELF or something similar.  If you could explain what you are trying to do a bit more, I'm sure we could give you a better answer.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you're trying to do, we could give you a more useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$your_url = 'https://jscompressor.com/';
if ($r == 'donald') {
    echo '<script>window.location.href="'.urlencode($your_url).'"</script>';
}
```